# How do i remove specific text from the file?

Tags: python, file-handling

I'm trying to remove some specific context from this subtitle file, but when I try to do this it completely erases the file into the blank. Please help me. Thank you.

[image: Here's how the file look like]

```
x=open("text.txt",'rb')for sub in x:
sub=sub.strip()
if sub.startswith('0',0,28): 
    x.remove()
```

//subtitle file

https://hastebin.com/ulupuwibix.makefile

Comment: Your code is invalid: some indentation probably got lost when you pasted it. Also, there is no way this code can do what you pretend that it does. Among others, file objects  have no `remove` method, so `x.remove` would cause an ` AttributeError`

Comment: To remove lines beginning with a timestamp in bash:  grep -v '^[0-9][0-9]:' file_in > file_out .  the pythonic way to do is available in the other comments/answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to replace this.

The regex pattern: `[0-9]+\n[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2},[0-9]+ --> [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2},[0-9]+\n`

```py
import re

with open("text.txt") as file:
    txt = re.sub(r"[0-9]+\n[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2},[0-9]+ --> [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2},[0-9]+\n", "", file.read())

print(txt)
```

**Sample contents of text.txt**

```
1
00:00:26,720 --> 00:00:31,720
Subtitles by <font color="#ff0000">explosiveskull</font>
Sync by <font color="#00ffff">GoldenBeard</font>

2
00:00:43,752 --> 00:00:45,621
(MEN CHATTERING INDISTINCTLY)
```

**Output**

```
Subtitles by <font color="#ff0000">explosiveskull</font>
Sync by <font color="#00ffff">GoldenBeard</font>

(MEN CHATTERING INDISTINCTLY)
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the file and store the file contents in a string:

```
with open("test.txt") as x:    
    data = x.read()
```

Now remove/ add any data to that string as you'd like:

```
// operations that you wish to perform on the content
```

Open it again in w+ mode and write the modified content to it:

```
with open("test.txt", w+) as x:    
    data = x.write(content)
```

Comment: @AnttiHaapala did that